# CSS drop down menu

Tags: css, menu, navigation, drop-down-menu

Been trying to get a "pure css" dropdown 
been trying for days to get a "simple" css drop down nav going can get the top level displayed and the second level hiding but can't make the sub items display on hover?? any help much appreciated sample Isolated is here::
css and html below paste bin
http://www.webdevout.net/test?01t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are probably because you've constructed your html wrongly. The sub-menu (`.level-two`) should be nested within the `.level-one` `li` elements:

```
<div id="navtree">
<ul class="level-one">
<li><a href="/about/" title="about">about</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact/" title="contact">contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/feeds/latest/" title="subscribe">subscribe</a></li>
<li><a href="/Test1/" title="Test1page">Test1</a>
  <ul class="level-two">
    <li><a href="/Test1/testsub/" title="test1subpage">Test1sub</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/Test2/" title="Test2 page">Test2</a>
  <ul class="level-two">
    <li><a href="/Test2/subpage2/" title="Testsubpage2">Testsubpage2</a></li>
</ul></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

If you then use the following css:

```
.level-one {display: inline; position: relative; }

.level-one {display: none; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 1em; /* adjust as necessary */ }

.level-one:hover .level-two {display: block; }
```

I think that should be enough to get you started. Feel free to ask any questions in comments, or update your question.

Also, since I'm assuming you're fairly new to this, I'd like to offer you the following references:

- For all things snazzy and wonderful with CSS menus: [CSS Play](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/), by Stu Nicholls.
- For an intro to some of the hows and whys: [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hybrid/).
- A brief introduction, from [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/menus/demo.html).

There are dozens, if not hundreds, more to be found...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response:
well the problem then is that I am using a generated HTML from Django navbar and it is generating the HTML.. any idea of how to change that without touching the original module,, ie inheritance? Bettr yet any how to fix it via CSS??

Comment: I'd also note that I can select the children to hide them,see code, why can't I make them appear???

Comment: Also posted this to the Google group for Django Navbar issue 25
http://code.google.com/p/django-navbar/issues/list

Comment: It appears the answer has been posted to Google groups http://code.google.com/p/django-navbar/issues/detail?id=25

Comment: Nicely done, I've not used django, but Doug seems extraorinarily patient guy; which tempts me to play with it some. =)

Answer (score 1):

The second level `<ul>` level must be children, you have this:

```
<li><a href="/Test2/" title="Test2 page">Test2</a></li>
<ul class="level-two">
 <li><a href="/Test2/subpage2/" title="Testsubpage2">Testsubpage2</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Change to this:

```
<li><a href="/Test2/" title="Test2 page">Test2</a>
 <ul class="level-two">
  <li><a href="/Test2/subpage2/" title="Testsubpage2">Testsubpage2</a></li>    
 </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css I'm sort of happy with that implements three level dropdown So far only tested in FF:

```
/* Inserted by Tom Brander for nested nav Allows for Three levels.. pattern can be extended if you want */
ul.level-one{
  margin-left:-10px; /* lines up 1st item with search box*/
}
ul.level-one li{
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  }
ul.level-one li:hover {
  background:#999ca0;
  }
.level-two {
  display: none;
  position :absolute;
  Left:0;
  top: 1em;
  }
.level-three {
  display: none;
  position :absolute;
  top: 0em;
  }
.level-one li:hover .level-two {
  display: block;
  background: #999ca0;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  }
.level-two li:hover .level-three {
  display: block;
  background: #999ca0;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 92px;  /* this moves the 3rd level over to the right but not too far, needs enough overlap so that you can move the mouse wthout the third level dissapearing */
  }
.level-three li:hover {display:block;}
```