# jQuery: hover link show/hide div

Tags: jquery, html, hover

This seems to be a beginners question (I've googled a lot since I am a beginner at JavaScript) but I still can't get it to work. Could someone please help me?

I have a list menu with numbered links. Each links has it's own submenu that I want to show/hide on mouse over. The link and the submenu are connected in the way that they have similar ID.

Like this...

Link:

```
    a id=815 class="menuItem" href="/default____815.aspx">
```

Hidden div:

```
    div id="subMenudiv815" class="HoverTopSubMenuBlock" style="display:none">
```

Since I have several menuItems I've tried to loop a function that's working when you specify the divs manually. This is what I've tried with:

```
var j = [66,815,1006,9581,1239,1206,816];
var menu = [];
var hoverdiv = [];
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    menu[i] = "#"+j[i];
    hoverdiv[i] = "#subMenudiv" + j[i];
    $(rubrik[i]).hover(function() {
        $(hoverdiv[i]).show();
    }, function() {
        $(hoverdiv[i]).delay(1000).hide(0);
    });
}
```

Ive tried to use the each()-function but that didn't help me much.

Comment: Hmm, the second part of you post means nothing to me. I'd suggest starting simple. If you want to do _something_ on the mouseevent event, I'd focus on that first. You can use the selector $("a.menuItem") to match links with the menuItem link. Write a jQuery snippet that does that and simply uses console.log to note when you mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery to make a dropdown menu. You can use just html and css.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">Link 1</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">Link 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="">Sub Link 1</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" title="">Sub Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
#nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav > li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#nav > li > a {
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #cccccc;
}

#nav > li:hover > a {

}

#nav > li > ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

#nav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#nav > li > ul > li { 
}
#nav > li > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    background: #cccccc;   
    padding: 0 10px;
}

#nav > li > ul > li:hover > a {

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BV9n6/)**

Here are some information on how to do this:

- [CSS drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188772/css-drop-down-menu)
- http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html
- http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but my css-files are already a bit messy. Short of time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A few things I see:

1. in your anchor link, you need quotes around your id value ( id="815" instead of id=815 )
2. You need to put the jQuery $ around your selector if you want to put them inside a variable and reuse them just by calling that variable ( menu[i] = $("#"+j[i]); )
3. I don't know where your rubrik[i] is coming from, but if you are trying to call an element based on it's position in the dom, you need to use the ":eq(x)" selector. Like if you want to grab the 3rd element with the class HoverTopSubMenuBlock, you can grab it with $(".HoverTopSubMenuBlock:eq(3)")

But if I were you, I would just do:

```
$(".menuItem").hover(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#subMenudiv" + id).show();
},function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#subMenudiv" + id).delay(1000).hide();
});
```

I think that would do it without all the loops and stuff.

Comment: Thank you! Eventually I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('a.menuItem').hover(function(){
    $('#subMenudiv' + this.id).show();
}, function(){
    $('#subMenudiv' + this.id).delay(1000).hide(0);
});
```

See this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/f3NM3/3/)

Greetings.

Comment: `.toggle()` is now depreciated and removed form 1.9

Comment: @ROYFinley That's toggle event method, not this method.

Comment: Thanks! Figured out exactly that solution all myself. :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2005500 - You should post your solution as an answer and accept it so others can see that your problem was solved, especially if you solved it yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help!

Thought I would get an email notification once my question got answered so I countinued trying, and got to the solution. Ended up with almost the same code as MG_Bautista suggested.

```
$('a.menuItem').hover(function(){
    $('#subMenudiv' + this.id).show();
}, function(){
    $('#subMenudiv' + this.id).delay(1000).hide(0);
});
```