# Navigation list that shows on hover.

Tags: html, css

I want to add my navigation in the sidebar, and there isn't space for it.

I want to set it up so that when I hover over a word such as (Links) a list will appear. But I'm not sure what code I should be using to accomplish this.

An example can be seen here: http://www.colourlovers.com/  when you hover over Browse it shows a list of other links.

```
<div id="navigation">

  <a href="http://aftermidnightworkouts.tumblr.com/tagged/healthyrecipes">Dear         
    Charlie</a><br>

   <a href="http://aftermidnightworkouts.tumblr.com/tagged  
    /healthyrecipes">Portfolio</a><br>

   <a href="http://aftermidnightworkouts.tumblr.com/tagged    
  /healthyrecipes">Aftermidnightworkouts</a><br>

   <a href="http://aftermidnightworkouts.tumblr.com/tagged  
     /healthyrecipes">Writings</a>   
         </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS drop down menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188772/css-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little bit of code to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/ZsAQb/

```
<ul id="navigation">

  <li>
      <a href="http://aftermidnightworkouts.tumblr.com/tagged/healthyrecipes">Dear Charlie</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
          <li class="item">
              subnav item1
          </li>
          <li class="item">
              subnav item2
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It's better to use a list for navigation menus like yours, it would be even better to wrap it in a nav tag (html5).

The trick is that you insert a child list for the subnavigation inside a list item of the main navigation and set it's css to be hidden by default. When you hover on a main navigation item you just target it's child subnavigation and display it

Answer (score 0):

Just google for CSS drop down menu, lots of pages about it, you can even have it generated and then inspect the code yourself (for example [here](http://cssmenumaker.com/css-drop-down-menu)). You just need a bit of css code that use `:hover` selector.